# Eager Spool 100%

Tags: sql-server, index, execution-plan

I have a query like below, when I execute it, the parallel query always takes very long time to finish, I found there is index spool(Eager Spool) which costs 100% in execution plan... How can I improve the query? 
Many Thanks!

```
WITH
CTE AS
(
      SELECT
            shipPK = sh.WS_PK
      FROM
            WorkShip AS sh
      WHERE
            sh.tbl_ship = @shipPK

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
            shipPK = sh.WS_PK
      FROM
            WorkShip AS sh 
            JOIN CTE    AS cte ON sh.tbl_ship = cte.shipPK
)
SELECT
      WorkPK = cte.shipPK,
      JobType = 'JS',
      ProcessTaskPK = t.PK
FROM
      CTE               AS cte
      JOIN ProcessTasks AS t ON cte.shipPK = t.P9_ParentID
WHERE
      t.RespondToCascadedEvents = 1
AND   t.SE_NKEvent = @EventCode

UNION ALL

SELECT
      WorkPK = bl.DL_PK,
      JobType = 'DL',
      ProcessTaskPK = t.PK
FROM
      SupplierBookingLine AS bl 
      JOIN ProcessTasks AS t ON bl.DL_PK = t.P9_ParentID
WHERE
      bl.DL_JS_ApprovedShipment = @shipPK
      AND t.RespondToCascadedEvents = 1
      AND t.SE_NKEvent = @EventCode

UNION ALL

SELECT
      WorkPK    = orderHeader.JD_PK,
      JobType  = 'JD',
      ProcessTaskPK = processTask.PK
FROM          
      JobOrderHeader AS orderHeader
      JOIN ProcessTasks AS processTask ON orderHeader.JD_PK = processTask.P9_ParentID
WHERE
      orderHeader.JD_JS = @shipPK
      AND processTask.RespondToCascadedEvents = 1
      AND processTask.SE_NKEvent = @EventCode
      AND processTask.SE_NKEvent not in ('DEP', 'ARV', 'ECM', 'ECC', 'CCC', 'CLR', 'CAV', 'DCA', 'DCF')
```

Comment: You combined three queries here. Which one is giving you the most trouble? The first (The recursive CTE) or the second (SupplierBookingLine) or the third (JobOrderHeader)? Execute them one at a time to narrow down the problem. After that you can add a link to the XML version of the actual query plan you get for that query. Also add the table definitions and any index definitions on the tables to the question.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, we use temp table to drop the cpu usage, and also changed MAXDOP, now I cannot see the query in top 10 now.